# Splitting a matrix into arrays with different column sizes

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, slice, reshape

I want to split a matrix into arrays with different column sizes. I'm able to do it with a for loop, however I'm curious if it could be done in a faster way using some command.

Let's say for example that I have the following matrix:

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3, 4]
          [5, 6, 7, 8]
          [9, 10, 11, 12]
          [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

Now I woud like to obtain a 2D-array which looks as follows:

```
desired_array = [[1]
                 [5, 6]
                 [9, 10, 11]
                 [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

I want this since I would like the sum per row of the desired_array. Maybe there is another solution to obtain that sum, without using a for loop?

Thank you!

Comment: look at the result of `tril` by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want the row-wise sum of the lower triangular matrix.

```
>>> np.tril(matrix).sum(1)
array([ 1, 11, 30, 58])
```